# Can Spring REST convert path variables to an object, like it is done with request parameters with @RequestBody?

Tags: spring, rest

With Spring REST the request parameters are converted to an object in case you do a post, and you use `@RequestBody`, for example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reservations")
class ReservationController{
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value="/postByName")
    public  Reservation save(@RequestBody Reservation reservation) {
        return reservationRepository.save(reservation);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I do, and this works fine, a Reservation is created:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"name\" : \"Foo\" }" http://localhost:8080/reservations/postByName
```

My question is if something exists when you use path variables instead of request parameters. So I should do something like:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/reservations/postByName/Foo
```

Now I do it by hand: in the code I create a Reservation with `new` and put the path variables in it.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) says:

> A @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc. Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type or throws a TypeMismatchException if it fails to do so. You can also register support for parsing additional data types. See the section called “Method Parameters And Type Conversion” and the section called “Customizing WebDataBinder initialization”.